# Remove duplicate data based on the same unix time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

multiple data on the same date. I am trying to remove the multiple data and have the data aligned based on the unix time given,
I tried using remove duplicate but its not working

```
            time    x     y
0  1648598400000  233  6758
1  1648598400000  234  6758
2  1648598403000  553  8678
3  1648598404000  987  8778
4  1648598405000  732  4535
5  1648598406000  234  7656
6  1648598406000  234  8977
7  1648598406000  465  7656
8  1648598406000  465  8977
```

Comment: to format code/data you have to use ``` instead of ''

Comment: what did you try? Show your code? What result do you expcet for this data? should it be first or last value for the same `time` ?

Comment: `df[ df['time'].duplicated() ]` ?

Comment: I tried using  df [ df['time'].duplicated() ] but it removes all the data. There are more than 3 data on the same time(UNIX time) I just wanted to remove all except one.

Comment: small correction - it needs `~` to get inverted result `df[ ~df['time'].duplicated() ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df[ ~df['time'].duplicated() ]` (with `~`) works for me.

I use `io` only to simulate file - so everyone can copy it.

```
data = '''            time    x     y
0  1648598400000  233  6758
1  1648598400000  234  6758
2  1648598403000  553  8678
3  1648598404000  987  8778
4  1648598405000  732  4535
5  1648598406000  234  7656
6  1648598406000  234  8977
7  1648598406000  465  7656
8  1648598406000  465  8977
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print( df[ ~df['time'].duplicated() ] )
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

            time    x     y
0  1648598400000  233  6758
1  1648598400000  234  6758
2  1648598403000  553  8678
3  1648598404000  987  8778
4  1648598405000  732  4535
5  1648598406000  234  7656
6  1648598406000  234  8977
7  1648598406000  465  7656
8  1648598406000  465  8977

--- after ---

            time    x     y
0  1648598400000  233  6758
2  1648598403000  553  8678
3  1648598404000  987  8778
4  1648598405000  732  4535
5  1648598406000  234  7656
```

---

If I use `duplicated(keep='last')` then it gives

```
--- after ---

            time    x     y
1  1648598400000  234  6758
2  1648598403000  553  8678
3  1648598404000  987  8778
4  1648598405000  732  4535
8  1648598406000  465  8977
```